# Call an random Array of Sounds once and play it with Button

Tags: objective-c, xcode6

I want to randomize an Array of Soundfiles.

```
- (void)generateRandomizedSounds {
    int randomSoundNumber = arc4random() % 4; //random number from 0 to 3

    NSLog(@"random sound number = %i", randomSoundNumber);

    NSString *effectTitle;

    switch (randomSoundNumber) {
        case 0:
            effectTitle = @"bell";
            break;
        case 1:
            effectTitle = @"brake";
            break;
        case 2:
            effectTitle = @"dog";
            break;
        case 3:
            effectTitle = @"bird";
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }
    SystemSoundID soundID;

    NSString *soundPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:effectTitle ofType:@"mp3"];
    NSURL *soundUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:soundPath];

    AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID ((__bridge CFURLRef)soundUrl,  &soundID);
    AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(soundID);

    return;
}
```

Ok, and now i want to play each case with a Button.

But everything i tried goes wrong with errors.

Comment: What did you try? What errors occurred?

Comment: i tried it with [self.soundID play], and with integrate the snippet from SystemSoundID to the Button, but nothing works...

Answer (score 0):

`AudioServicesPlaySystemSound()` function cannot play any MP3 files. The function supports only these file formats that are `.caf`, `.aac`, or `.wav` and the sound must be 30 seconds or less.

> Sound files that you play using this function must be:
>   No longer than 30 seconds in duration In linear PCM or IMA4 (IMA/ADPCM) format Packaged in a .caf, .aif, or .wav file

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AudioToolbox/Reference/SystemSoundServicesReference/index.html#//apple_ref/c/func/AudioServicesPlaySystemSound

So if the `clock.mp3` is less than 30 seconds in duration, you can play the sound if convert the file format.

To convert `mp3` to `caf`, for example using `afconvert` command, like below:

```
$ afconvert -f caff -d ima4 bell.mp3 bell.caf
```

If not (the sound is more than 30 seconds), use `AVPlayer` of `AVFoundation.framework` instead.

```
NSString *soundFilePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"bell" ofType:@"mp3"];
NSURL *soundFileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:soundFilePath];

AVAudioPlayer *player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:soundFileURL  error:nil];
[player play];
```